# Error says: 'Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays'

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have already looked into many questions like this but none of them could help me out. I'm receiving an object that returns a list of cities with their names, habitants and states.
Here's my http service request:

```
cidadesUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/cidades';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  listar(): Observable<Cidade[]>{
    return this.http.get<Cidade[]>(this.cidadesUrl);
  }
```

and here's the calling to the service:

```
  cidades!: Cidade[];

  constructor(private cidadeService:CidadeService) { }

  listar(){
    this.cidadeService.listar().subscribe(data => { this.cidades = data });
    console.log(this.cidades);
  }
```

and my html:

```
<p-table [paginator]="true" [rows]="4" responsiveLayout="scroll">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
      <tr>
          <th>Nome</th>
          <th>Habitantes</th>
          <th>Estado</th>
          <th>Ações</th>
      </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" *ngFor="let cidade of tabela">
      <tr>
          <td>{{cidade.nome}}</td>
          <td>{{cidade.qtdHabitantes | number}}</td>
          <td>{{cidade.estado}}</td>
          <td class="acoes">
            <button pButton icon="pi pi-pencil" pTooltip="Editar" tooltipPosition="top"></button>
            <button pButton class="p-button-danger" icon="pi pi-trash"  pTooltip="Excluir" tooltipPosition="top"></button>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Tabela property:

```
@Input() tabela!: Cidade[];
```

I don't know why but when the page loads, i get the error:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

When I open the Network tab in console, the cities are there, but they dont show up in the table
[image]

Hoping that i could find a answer to this

Comment: You have for ngFor `let cidade of tabela` - what is `tabela`? Did you mean `let cidade of cidades`? If that doesn't fix the problem, can you share the service's response, the content of `cidades`?

Comment: are you using prime ng here? if yes can you please give us complete template including p-table?

Comment: Hi @AakashGarg, i just added the p-table

Comment: Do ngFor for `let cidade of cidades.content` or set `this.cidades = data.content` since there is a top-level key in the object.

Comment: Hey @MishaMashina, when i try to set `this.cidades = data.content` it says that `Property 'content' does not exist on type 'Cidade[]'`

Comment: I see you've added `tabela` to issue description. How do you set the value for `tabela`? Is it actually `cidades`, just sent to child? Please share code around those variables as well as `Cidade` interface

Comment: Hi @MishaMashina I have tried to set the value for tabela as cidades but it didnt work, so tabela its just an input rn. Obs: i have changed the code like the answer of Aakash garg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You p-table code is wrong it should be :-

```
<p-table [value]="tabela" [paginator]="true" [rows]="4" responsiveLayout="scroll">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
      <tr>
          <th>Nome</th>
          <th>Habitantes</th>
          <th>Estado</th>
          <th>Ações</th>
      </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-cidade>
      <tr>
          <td>{{cidade.nome}}</td>
          <td>{{cidade.qtdHabitantes | number}}</td>
          <td>{{cidade.estado}}</td>
          <td class="acoes">
            <button pButton icon="pi pi-pencil" pTooltip="Editar" tooltipPosition="top"></button>
            <button pButton class="p-button-danger" icon="pi pi-trash"  pTooltip="Excluir" tooltipPosition="top"></button>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the other error dissapeared, but now im getting the error `ERROR TypeError: data.slice is not a function`

Comment: thats another question, please post another question with complete error log and debugging details.

Comment: maybe try changing your input tabela to @Input() tabela!: Cidade[] = [];

Comment: this didnt solve, im going to post another question rn, thanks!

Comment: please mark this as answer, if it helped.